# Crash in performBatchUpdates while updating collectionView

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following stack trace:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1d2bbde88 __exceptionPreprocess + 164 (NSException.m:202)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1cbef78d8 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:356)
2   Foundation                      0x1cd4e5b4c -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 188 (NSException.m:242)
3   UIKitCore                       0x1d5082998 -[UICollectionView _endItemAnimationsWithInvalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:animator:collectionViewAnimator:] + 3964 (UICollectionView.m:9492)
4   UIKitCore                       0x1d4fe17bc -[UICollectionView _performBatchUpdates:completion:invalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:animator:animationHandler:] + 520 (UICollectionView.m:11824)
5   FieldService                    0x1006f2f0c specialized EditLatestNewsListViewController.controllerDidChangeContent(_:) + 276 (EditLatestNewsListViewController.swift:170)
6   FieldService                    0x1006f1920 EditLatestNewsListViewController.controllerDidChangeContent(_:) + 4 (:0)
7   FieldService                    0x1006f1920 @objc EditLatestNewsListViewController.controllerDidChangeContent(_:) + 48
8   CoreData                        0x1da3f0c04 __82-[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _core_managedObjectContextDidChange:]_block_invoke + 5576 (NSFetchedResultsController.m:2329)
9   CoreData                        0x1da4147e8 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 156 (NSManagedObjectContext.m:3964)
10  CoreData                        0x1da414338 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 208 (NSManagedObjectContext.m:4075)
11  CoreData                        0x1da3f2c98 -[NSFetchedResultsController _core_managedObjectContextDidChange:] + 124 (NSFetchedResultsController.m:2363)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x1d2beb404 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 148 (CFNotificationCenter.c:661)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x1d2c92474 ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 88 (CFNotificationCenter.c:175)
14  CoreFoundation                  0x1d2c75724 _CFXRegistrationPost + 440 (CFNotificationCenter.c:201)
15  CoreFoundation                  0x1d2bffa08 _CFXNotificationPost + 704 (CFNotificationCenter.c:1193)
16  Foundation                      0x1ccffcffc -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 92 (NSNotification.m:518)
17  CoreData                        0x1da40cd70 -[NSManagedObjectContext _createAndPostChangeNotification:deletions:updates:refreshes:deferrals:wasMerge:] + 1796 (NSManagedObjectContext.m:8631)
18  CoreData                        0x1da4214bc -[NSManagedObjectContext _processRecentChanges:] + 2508 (NSManagedObjectContext.m:7722)
19  CoreData                        0x1da40c518 -[NSManagedObjectContext _mergeChangesFromDidSaveDictionary:usingObjectIDs:] + 3576 (NSManagedObjectContext.m:3701)
20  CoreData                        0x1da4154d8 -[NSManagedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:] + 376 (NSManagedObjectContext.m:3730)
21  MagicalRecord                   0x10237f228 +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) rootContextDidSave:] + 448 (NSManagedObjectContext+MagicalRecord.m:236)
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x1da18c4b4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1518)
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x1da18dfdc _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x1da19c7f4 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 928 (inline_internal.h:2632)
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x1da19c444 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44 (queue.c:7887)
26  CoreFoundation                  0x1d2c4e6f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16 (CFRunLoop.c:1780)
27  CoreFoundation                  0x1d2c30058 __CFRunLoopRun + 2036 (CFRunLoop.c:3147)
28  CoreFoundation                  0x1d2c34ed4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612 (CFRunLoop.c:3418)
29  GraphicsServices                0x20bf36368 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2196)
30  UIKitCore                       0x1d51133d0 -[UIApplication _run] + 888 (UIApplication.m:3745)
31  UIKitCore                       0x1d5113034 UIApplicationMain + 340 (UIApplication.m:5335)
32  FieldService                    0x1005c3214 main + 68 (AppDelegate.swift:20)
33  dyld                            0x1f12a0960 start + 2528 (dyldMain.cpp:1170)
```

This is how it looks like `controllerDidChangeContent`:

```
private var collectionViewChanges = [[NSFetchedResultsChangeType: [IndexPath]]]()
func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    
    collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({ [weak self] in
        
        if let collectionViewChanges = self?.collectionViewChanges {
            for collectionViewChange in collectionViewChanges {
                
                for (type, indexPaths) in collectionViewChange {
                    
                    switch type {
                    case .insert:
                        
                        self?.collectionView?.insertItems(at: indexPaths)
                        
                    case .delete:
                        
                        self?.collectionView?.deleteItems(at: indexPaths)
                        
                    case .update:
                        
                        self?.collectionView?.reloadItems(at: indexPaths)
                        
                    case .move:
                        
                        if let indexPath = indexPaths.first, let newIndexPath = indexPaths.last {
                            self?.collectionView?.moveItem(at: indexPath, to: newIndexPath)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        delegate?.contentDidChange()
        updateView()
    })
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should try handling deletions before insertions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use reloadData only of the cell you reloading was not moved (IndexPath before and after animation is the same). What is it, you can't use it for animated cell move.

Also, order in which updates are performed absolutely does not matter. It looks like all "remove" actions are using indices in old unmodified collection and "adding" actions are using indices in resulting collection

reloadData presumes old IndexPath and new IndexPath is the same.